# How to multiply a numpy array by a list to get a multidimentional array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, array-broadcasting

In Python, I have a list and a numpy array.

I would like to multiply the array by the list in such a way that I get an array where the 3rd dimension represents the input array multiplied by each element of the list. Therefore:

```
in_list = [2,4,6]
in_array = np.random.rand(5,5)
result = ...
np.shape(result) ---> (3,5,5)
```

where (0,:,:) is the input array multiplied by the first element of the list (2); 
(1,:,:) is the input array multiplied by the second element of the list (4), etc.

I have a feeling this question will be answered by broadcasting, but I'm not sure how to go around doing this.

Comment: Does `np.multiply.outer(in_list, in_array)` give what you need?

Comment: Yes, this works. could you please write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`np.multiply.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html). The `outer` method is defined for any NumPy "ufunc", including multiplication. Here's a demonstration:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: in_list = [2, 4, 6]

In [3]: in_array = np.random.rand(5, 5)

In [4]: result = np.multiply.outer(in_list, in_array)

In [5]: result.shape
Out[5]: (3, 5, 5)

In [6]: (result[1, :, :] == in_list[1] * in_array).all()
Out[6]: True
```

As you suggest, broadcasting gives an alternative solution: if you convert `in_list` to a 1d NumPy array of length `3`, you can then reshape to an array of shape `(3, 1, 1)`, and then a multiplication with `in_array` will broadcast appropriately:

```
In [9]: result2 = np.array(in_list)[:, None, None] * in_array

In [10]: result2.shape
Out[10]: (3, 5, 5)

In [11]: (result2[1, :, :] == in_list[1] * in_array).all()
Out[11]: True
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested a %timeit on the two different codes using a 500x500 array and a list with 100 elements. There is no significant difference in the time the different methods take.